# Compounding more frequently seems to decrease total amount when using APYs?

Tags: exponential-function, finance

Interest rates are often given in terms of annual growth, even when compounding happens more often than once a year. To account for this, I read that we can use the following transformation to get the periodic compounding rate, $r$.

$$ r = (1 + \text{apy})^{1/n} $$

Where apy is the percentage annual growth, and n is the number of compounding periods.

Though approximations exist, my understanding is that this is justified by the fact that, for a balance $B$, one year of growth produces
\begin{align}
B \cdot \underbrace{r \cdot r \cdot \ldots \cdot r}_{n \text{ times}}
& = B (1 + \text{apy})^{1/n} (1 + \text{apy})^{1/n} \ldots (1 + \text{apy})^{1/n} \\ 
& = B(1 + \text{apy})
= B + B(\text{apy})
\end{align}

Which is the annual rate applied once, as we should expect.

But problems arise when we consider the fact that people periodically contribute to their accounts. When I do the math, assuming contributions are made at the start of each compounding period, compounding more frequently *decreases* the overall growth. This, surely, cannot be right.

My thinking can be expressed two ways. First, mathematically, then as an equivalent computer program.

- Let $a$ be the contribution amount.
- Let $t$ be the number of contributions per year.
- Let $P$ be the initial balance.
- Let $n$ be the number of compounding periods. Assume $n$ divides $t$ for simplicity.
- Let $y$ be the number of years.

$$ P ( 1 + r)^y + a {t \over n} {(1+r)^{1/n} \over {(1+r)^{1/n}-1}} ((1+r)^y - 1)$$

Alternatively, as a C program, we see the same results.

```
int main() {

  double apy = 7.2;       // annual growth rate
  double start = 5000;    // starting amount
  double add   = 2000;    // amount to add each contribution
  int compounds = 4;      // number of times to compound
  int additions = 12;     // number of times to contribute
  int years = 20;         // number of years to grow

  double balance = start;
  double rate = pow(1 + apy/100.0, 1.0/compounds) - 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < years; i++) {

    for (int c = 0; c < compounds; c++) {

      for (int m = 0; m < additions/compounds; m++)
        balance += add;

      balance *= 1 + rate;
    }
  }

  printf("Balance: %.2lf\n", balance);
}
```

In either case, we can tabulate the following when $P = 5000$, $a = 2000$, $\text{apy} = 7.2$, $t = 12$ and $y = 20$,

> The balance is $1,098,139.14$ when $n = 1$.
>
> The balance is $1,070,593.39$ when $n = 4$.
>
> The balance is $1,064,536.20$ when $n = 12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that with less compounding the money is in the account longer.  Let us take a one year term and compare annual vs. semiannual compounding at $10\%$.  If you deposit $1$ at the start of the year, annual compounding gets you $1.1$ while semiannual gets you $1.1025$ as you would expect.  But if you contribute $1$ split over the periods, for semiannual interest the second $0.5$ is only in the account for half the year, so it only draws half a year's interest.  Again, $1$ in the annual account gives $1.1$, but in the semiannual account it only gives $1.07625$